# How to use Gouramy fish sauce?

Tags: sauce, fish

Out of curiosity I bought some Gouramy fish sauce:

[image]

The jar contains a mixture of a very salty sauce and some fish chunks. However, the bones have not been removed and the chunks are rather chewy. This makes it almost impossible to eat the chunks without injuring your mouth. How is this product usually prepared? Are there any recipes which call for it?

Comment: Mắm cá sặc is fermented fish, not fish sauce.